# How to test modified FreeBSD source code?

Tags: kernel, compiling, freebsd, source

I am trying to modify the default congestion control algorithm in FreeBSD (NewReno) by creating a copy of the source file (`cc_newreno.c`, located in `/usr/src/sys/netinet/cc`) called `cc_newreno_mod.c` and making changes to it.

Suppose I have made some modifications. How do I test them? Compiling the `cc_newreno_mod.c` directly (using the built-in C compiler) results in multiple errors, some of which seem strange (for example `netinet/cc/cc_module.h file not found`, although the file clearly is there).

Should I build a new Kernel? Will the module from the changed file be created automatically? Or am I totally wrong and I should take a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compiling kernel module you should create `Makefile` and to include kernel module makefile `/usr/src/share/mk/bsd.kmod.mk` for example:

```
# Note: It is important to make sure you include the <bsd.kmod.mk>  makefile after declaring the KMOD and SRCS variables.

# Declare Name of kernel module
KMOD    =  module

# Enumerate Source files for kernel module

SRCS    =  module.c

# Include kernel module makefile
.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

And finally you run make to compile it so you can test it if it compiles properly.
And as it is not presented in kernel modules (`/boot/kernel/*.ko`), but it is listed in `sys/conf/files` I think you should recompile your kernel to apply changes. For more info you can see this [page](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html). As it is a copy of `cc_newreno.c` you can rename your original `/usr/src/sys/netinet/cc/cc_newreno.c` to something else for saving it copy your new one there and recompile.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip, with the help of `Makefile` I was able to compile the `cc_newreno_mod.c` (a copy of the original `cc_newreno.c`), no problem, however I ran into a new issue, when loading in the module with `kldload cc_newreno_mod.ko` I got error 17...

Any tips on what went wrong? Is it something related to the Module naming, or is it because `newreno` is the default congestion control algorithm?

Comment: The error is that it is already registered, so you have to try to do the second part of the answer (recompiling kernel).

Comment: It's strange - I did change the module data to make the system think it's a different module, it's possible that I missed something...Maybe I should change the default CC algorithm, so, on boot, for example `cc_vegas` is loaded? Would that help to load the `cc_newreno_mod` ?

About the Kernel recompiling - I tried the idea suggested [in this forum](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.devel.net/38014), by adding the `/usr/src/sys/netinet/cc/cc_newreno_mod.c optional inet | inet6` line to the `/usr/src/sys/conf/files` file, but it seems that the module was not built...Any ideas on that?

Comment: Thank you for checking up & your assistance! I am now able to make the module. To make it loadable, I had to change it's ID data, since it did conflict with the `cc_newreno.c`, which is the default congestion control algorithm that is started upon boot.

Answer (score 0):

netinet is currently not a kernel module, so i suggest to add your modified file to sys/conf/files instead.